# How do I set a Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession's socket to TCP_NODELAY?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

My initial try was to get the socket and set it to no delay after construction.

```
client_session.socket().setNoDelay(true);
```

That threw

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Poco::Net::InvalidSocketException'
what():  Invalid socket
```

I then tried to construct my http client session with my own socket that I set the no delay myself - it threw the same exception.

How do I make my http client have TCP_NODELAY?

Comment: Can I ask why? You should never, ever set no delay on an HTTP connection because HTTP is a request/response protocol.

Comment: There are, of course, [cases](https://t37.net/nginx-optimization-understanding-sendfile-tcp_nodelay-and-tcp_nopush.html) when TCP_NODELAY makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Alex Yeah, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: can't see anything in the question that would indicate that; e.g. nginx [enables it by default](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#tcp_nodelay) for keepalive, apache has it by default [on all httpd sockets](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tcp-ip-options-for-high-performance-data-transmission/); the fact that it has different effects on linux than other platforms is probably a topic for another discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As exception says - you are trying to set option [on invalid socket](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/8513b11a8f16e23ac4ff172c74950a865ba0f327/Net/src/SocketImpl.cpp#L687). However, there is no need to set TCP_NODELAY because [HTTPSession](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/9d259ac02f880a486ebef30acc4e5e83d3e87b5f/Net/src/HTTPSession.cpp#L186) does it on connect.

Comment: Thanks - I forgot to update my question after I looked at the code.